# Безобидная XSS/HTML-Injection

Tags: javascript, html, безопасность, защита, xss

к примеру:

есть на странице кнопка "Назад" -

```
<a href="*REFERER*">BACK</a>
```

как вы видите, туда просто подставляется реферер из заголовка... если изменить значение из заголовка, так: `"><script>alert(0)</script>`, то понятно, что исполнится код...

Вопрос: **насколько опасна подобная атака?** **Что можно сделать имея такую дыру?** Ведь по сути, вставляемый код подобным образом, можно исполнить и в консоли

Comment: "вставляемый код подобным образом, можно исполнить и в консоли"
Только у себя, другого пользователя вряд ли получится заставить открыть консоль и выполнить произвольный код, тут уж проще заставить вирус какой-нибудь скачать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, уязвимости нет, подмена заголовка на вашей стороне может навредить только вам. Вот если бы в REFERER не кодировалась двойная кавычка как `%22`, была бы уязвимость.

Comment: допустим, она не кодируется, передается прямой текст - `"><script>alert(0)</script>`.. как эксплуатировать такую уязвимость?

Comment: если реферер не взаимодействует с БД, то это просто HTML вставка, и не представляет собой уязвимость?

Comment: Если верно то, что вы написали, т.е. "подставляется реферер из заголовка..." и "допустим, она не кодируется, передается прямой текст ...", то создаете скрипт `site/1.html`, где будет `<iframe src="site/2.html?"><script>{скрипт, ворующий куки}</script>" width="1" height="1"></iframe>` и другой скрипт `site/2.html`, где будет `<script>location.href = '{ссылка на ваш сайт с уязвимостью}';</script>`. И чтобы украсть куки у пользователя достаточно ему перейти по `site/1.html`. Напоминаю, chrome может и не выполнить скрипт из-за xss auditor'а.

Comment: спасибо! теперь понял суть атаки! а если на атакуемом сайта стоит `X-Frame-Options`?

Comment: @cmd Если стоит `X-Frame-Options`, то я бы делал так: `site/1.html` перенаправляет на `site/2.html?"><script>{скрипт, ворующий куки, перенаправляющий после этого на site/3.html}</script>`. В принципе, можно было делать просто одну страницу, перенаправляющую на этот уязвимый сайт, но у Вас же ещё стоит задача, чтобы пользователь ничего не заподозрил, т.е. ссылка, которую вы скинули пользователю, не должна быть подозрительной(не содержать вредоносный скрипт) + по ссылке должно быть обычное содержимое(ну скажем видос), в прочем, ничего Вам не мешает вместо `site/3.html` указывать видео на youtube

Answer (score 1):

Имея такую дыру можно получить куки другого юзера, после чего установить эти куки себе и сидеть с его аккаунта(если конечно на куках не стоит httponly) или как минимум выполнять произвольный запрос на данный сайт(получив csrf_token с помощью этой дыры).

Comment: как именно? чтобы получить куки другого пользователя нужна активная XSS, не?

Comment: в данном случае, нет активной XSS, только пассивная, если значение просто подставляется из заголовка... меня интересует пассивные такого типа

Comment: Только пассивная? А если сделать скажем страничку `site/1.html`, где будет iframe с `site/2.html?"><script>alert(0)</script>`, а в `site/2.html` будет перенаправление на ваш этот сайт с уязвимостью?

Comment: кстати, проверяйте наличие уязвимости в FF, потому что в chrome есть xss auditor, который блокирует некоторые xss, например которые есть в get параметре, насчет REFERER не знаю

Comment: `site.ru/?act=<script>alert(0)</script>` - вы это имеете ввиду? Повторюсь: ссылка для кнопки "назад" подставляется из заголовка `REFERER`, а не из адресной строки

Comment: Ну, и? Если у вас в `site/2.html?"><script>alert(0)</script>` будет скрипт `location.href = 'xss/xss.php';`, то в заголовках к `xss/xss.php` REFERER будет `site/2.html?%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert(0)%3C/script%3E`(это если выводить REFERER в php как `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];`, там уязвимости не будет, если url декодируется - есть)

Comment: И при нажатим на кнопку "назад", обратно будет попадать на site/2.html?

Comment: А зачем жать кнопку "назад"? Вам нужно выполнить свой скрипт на чужом сайте. Давайте разберемся, что вы вот тут имеете ввиду: "...если изменить значение из заголовка..."? Каким образом? Для других юзеров только через перенаправление с вашего сайта.

Comment: каким образом мне нужно переадресовывать пользователей, чтобы выполнить вредоносный код на сайте с такой уязвимость?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33977/discussion-between-cladoxylon-and-cmd).